# JDialog Modality Behavior

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a message I want to display with some information in a modeless JDialog. The parent class will call the dispose method to close it at the right point. Here is the code I have:

```
    private static void waitMessage() {
    JOptionPane msg=new JOptionPane("Trying to get probes. Please wait ...",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
            null,new Object[]{},null);
    waitDialog=msg.createDialog("Probe Scan");
    waitDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    waitDialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.MODELESS);
    waitDialog.setSize(300,100);
    waitDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem is that when I set ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL the message displays as expected. Of course the JDialog blocks which is not what I need.

[image: Correct Pane]

However, when I set ModalityType.MODELESS, I get this:

[image: Incorrect Pane]

The JDialog does not block but the message text does not show up. Can someone explain why the ModalityType munges up the pane? TIA.

Comment: I don't see that issue in my env

Comment: Just curious: Does it become properly displayed when you resize the dialog?

Comment: No. Resizing does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding a `JOptionPane` as the content for a `JDialog`, doesn't look right to me.

`JOptionPane` has a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#createDialog(java.lang.String)) designed to create a relevant `JDialog` instance, so better try that :

```
waitDialog = msg.createDialog("Probe Scan");
```

Comment: I picked up that method from a search I did. I'll give yours a try. Thanks.

Comment: After looking into this more, I think this will not do what I need. I cannot see how to create this so that the user cannot close it. There is no 'SetDefaultCloseOperation' method. I also cannot see how to close it programmatically either as it seems it has no 'dispose' method. Am I missing something?

Comment: The created dialog has the same methods as any other JDialog, you can call them as you did in your example , including setDefraultCloseOperation.

Comment: Hmm. Not working for me. My IDE (Eclipse) is giving me missing method errors on those.

Comment: I got it to compile now but get the same results. I've updated the original post to show the new code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I decided that modeless does not work as I expected and it is indeed a timing problem. That task is not being permitted to finish the display by the parent. It cannot really be used in my context. I now have a class that generates that pane using 'invokelater'. I'm still having trouble and need to play with it more but failing that it will be a separate topic.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot close the dialog programmatically is that you do not keep a reference to the dialog. One way to do that is to have the waitMessage() method return the waitDialog instance. Or you can do as @Berger suggests.

Also,

```
waitDialog.setSize(300,100);
waitDialog.setVisible(true);
waitDialog.pack();
```

Why call setSize() and also pack() ? Make up your mind - do you want it a specifie size, or do you want it to appear its preferred size? And you should call setVisible() AFTER calling either setSize or pack.

> There is no 'SetDefaultCloseOperation' method.

But there is a `setDefaultCloseOperation` method. (note the lower case first letter)

Comment: I think I am on to the cause of the problem. When the parent of this method creates a JOptionPane with an OK button, this pane then changes and displays correctly. Does that not imply I have some kind of timing issue when modeless?